# Read a text file then save to the database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, text

**Scenario:**
I need a program using VB.NET that read line by line of the text file/s then save it to the database (MS SQL Server).
**Note/s:**
Text files data are not the same to other text files.
Other text files data are not included in inserting/saving into the database.
In saving a line/s into the database it will be split by lines length and the next line is also included.
**Question/s:**
Is it possible to check/choose a specific line on the text file before inserting/saving into the database?
Is there a way to choose some lines on the text file, for example: line #3 up to line #6 will be added in the table # 1 then line # 7 up to 9 will be added in the table # 2?

Any answers are highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: To answer your questions: Yes, and Yes. Now what? Please show what you have tried and ask about the problems you encounter completing this task yourself.

Comment: @Scott: Actually, I already made a program but I think it is a junk. I can save some lines into the database from the searched strings using "Contains". But I want to include the line after the string searched from a range of lines (ex: line # 1 were the string searched then line # 2 up to line #6 are also included to be save into the database).

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz - post your code, no matter how bad you think it is. This site is for helping people with their code, not writing it for them. People will provide help if you show that you have tried. :-)

Comment: @Karl: I updated my posts with my junk codes. I want to include the next line after the searched string (Contains) then save it to the database (i want a code that can locate a line/s position on the text).